# Don't understand answer to my question

Tags: discussion

I asked the question at - 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/240466/help-needed-to-install-expansion-cards - unfortunately I don't understand the answer and I don't see a way to directly reply to the answer. I'm new to ask ununtu.

Answer (score 2):

You can always edit your question (click on *edit* below the question) **and** you can add a comment (like Rinzwind did, click on *add comment*) to get things clarified.

See my comment to your original question for an explanation.

Comment: In order to comment on posts other than your own, you need the [comment everywhere](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment) privilege, however.

Comment: except for answers on your question. :-)

Comment: That's true as well, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the forum help and thanks for the answers to my original question.